# Determine target API

Tags: android, android-api-levels

Is there a way for an Android app to determine its target API level? (Particularly in the case of a JAR library, which cannot influence which apps it is embedded in, while app developers may not be able to change the code of the JAR.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given `context`, call:

```
context.getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
```

Same for `minSdkVersion`, which will give you the minimum SDK version.